# Please explain this python loop which evaluates to an array and is sum()ed

Tags: python, algorithm, for-loop

I've seen loops like this a lot on hackerrank but I still don't understand how they work. Why does it have a constant integer '1' in it? Shouldn't it be 'i' instead of '1'? Can anyone please explain this to me.

```
sum (1 for i in l if i >= a and i <= b)
```

Credit where credit is due. I copied this loop from a very elegant solution to a problem by Shashwat. The problem was 'Sherlock and Squares' in hackerrank algorithms the for curious ones.

Comment: Try breaking it into two steps and printing the intermediate result to your terminal or in the interpreter. `list_to_sum = [1 for i in l if i >= a and i <= b]` This is what is being passed to `sum`.

Comment: It is counting the list elements that meet that condition. You could rewrite that as `sum (bool(a <= i <= b) for i in l)` if that makes more sense to you.

Comment: `sum(1 for i in l if a <= i <= b)` is slightly more idomatic

Comment: I question the use of this expression.
The solution is floor(sqrt(b)) - ceil(sqrt(a)) + 1.
The original problem has no stricture against built-in functions, so I'm wondering why you'd solve the problem with the above comprehension.  It's a nice Python trick (although I generally use **len** instead of **sum(1)**).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know your values so let's assume:

```
>>> l = list(range(10))
>>> a = 4
>>> b = 7
```

If you break down your line of code into a couple of steps and print the intermediate results it's clearer:

```
>>> [1 for i in l if i >= a and i <= b]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

This is what gets passed to `sum`. (When you leave off the square brackets it implicitly becomes a generator but this is what it looks like as a list.)

In case you don't understand the comprehension, it's equivalent to this:

```
>>> result = []
>>> for i in l:
...   if i >= a and i <= b:
...     result.append(1)
... 
>>> result
[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

The summation would be equivalent to changing `result = []` to `result = 0` and `result.append(1)` to `result += 1`.

Answer (score 1):

In your example they're basically adding 1 to a variable for every item in l if the item is larger than or equal to a and the item is smaller than or equal to b.

This is basically equal to this code:

```
x = []
for i in l:
    if i >=a and i <= b:
        x.append(1)
sum(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sum (1 for i in l if i >= a and i <= b)
```

What this is doing, is going to create a generator expression of 1s only if the condition `i >= a and i <= b` passes while iterating over `l` and `i` being your iterator.

Then, `sum` will add all the 1s together.